# Android - Bottom Navigation menu selected item's icon color is not changing due to fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, bottomnavigationview, material-components

The color of the selected item of the Bottom Navigation is **not changing**, although i have provided the the drawable file which governs the changes of the color. I have tried so may times but i can't find the mistake in the code.

Please Help!

This is the Bottom Navigation

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/bottomBackground"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/icon_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
```

This is the icon_color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Edit :

When i Remove this piece of code it works fine

```
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if(id == R.id.navigation_library) {
                loadFragment(new LibraryFragment());
            }
            else if (id == R.id.navigation_for_you) {
                loadFragment(new ForYouFragment());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Why does this code interfering with my feature.

Comment: Move the icon_color selector in the color folder.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i can't find the color folder. can you please suggest where to look

Comment: Just create the `res/color` folder and put the file inside. Refer it with `app:itemTextColor="@color/icon_color"`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked

Comment: Thanks for your support @GabrieleMariotti I finally solved it.

Comment: Your issue is in the `onNavigationItemSelected` as described in the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
       ...
       return false;  //Use true in your case
    }
```

You can check the [doc:](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

> *Returns*
>
> **`boolean`**   **true to display the item as the selected item and false if the item should not be selected**. Consider setting non-selectable items as disabled preemptively to make them appear non-interactive.

Also in you layout use:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        app:itemTextColor="@color/icon_color"
```

moving the selector in the `res/color` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Replace false with true in your code. It will work.

```
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        //your code

        return true;
    }
```